# How to make Vi default?

Tags: vim, default-programs, vi

Apparently Ubuntu 11.10 uses Vim when I type

`vi filename`

How do I force Ubuntu to use Vi instead?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to install the actual *vi* package, which is *nvi* on Ubuntu.

`sudo apt-get install nvi`

You might also need to run the line below if *nvi* isn't picked up automatically as the default provider for *vi*.

`sudo update-alternatives --config vi`

Comment: I think you want
`sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

Answer (score 6):

man update-alternatives

vi even get special mention as an example.

Comment: A very useful man page.  They say it's better to teach someone how to fish than to just give him a fish... probably the down-voter didn't agree with that.  I upvoted you to cancel it :)

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Answer (score 3):

Check out:

Decide which vi-compatible tool you want to use.

vim, elvis, nvi, vigor (etc). You may want to study the output of `apt-cache search editor |grep vi` and look for other alternatives. `nvi` claims to be "bug for bug" compatible with vi.

Once you've done that, install the package:

```
apt-get install $YOURCHOICE
```

then run

```
update-alternatives --config vi
```

and choose $YOURCHOICE as the one to set as "vi".

Answer (score 2):

If by any chance you just want to get rid of Vim specific features, you can also make sure that Vim runs [in compatible mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-C).

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you type `vi` in Ubuntu, it actually runs Vim, because over time the Linux OSs have updated and some are now using Vim. If you still want to use vi, you have to install the package that directly runs `vi` instead of `vim`.

To install *just* `vi`:

```
sudo apt install nvi
```

You can also use `vim-tiny` (preinstalled.)

Another solution is to type `busybox vi` in the terminal. This brings the default Vi installed on 18.04/18.10. This version is a very small clone of vi.

If you want to make it your default for when you type `editor`, type `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`. To make it the default for when you type `edit`, add `export EDITOR="/usr/bin/nvi"` to your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score -1):

vim is set as your default editor. Put this as your default editor by setting this environment variable-->  export EDITOR=vi

Comment: This won't work if the *vi* symlink is still pointing to vim.